# Meaning of 彼は自殺の恐れがある

Tags: meaning

> 彼は自殺の恐れがある

So does this sentence mean...

> (1) He is afraid of suicide
> (2) He is suicidal

If it's (1), how would the sentence change to mean (2)? Or vice versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

～の恐れ only means either of those things:

- possessive:

  > 彼の恐れ *his fear*
- modifier:

  > 一瞬の恐れ *a momentary fear; a flash of fear*
- "worrisome possibility of" (risk/susceptibility...):

  > 逃亡の恐れ *being a flight risk*
  > 大雪の恐れ *(unwelcome) likelihood of heavy snow*

So your sentence always means (2). Similarly, [clause] + 恐れ is always appositive, such as:

> 地震で倒壊する恐れ *risk of collapsing during an earthquake*

Although, as verb, 恐れる "fear" takes a direct object such as 人を恐れる "be afraid of people", its synonymous noun phrase is made with ～への恐れ or ～に対する恐れ, thus:

> 自殺の恐れ *possibility of suicide*
> 自殺への恐れ *being afraid of committing suicide*

---

**PS**: In my third definition, ～のおそれ should be prescriptively [spelled with 虞 instead of 恐れ](https://www.bunka.go.jp/seisaku/bunkashingikai/kokugo/hokoku/pdf/ijidokun_140221.pdf), but it is not obeyed by many.